# Excel Partial Look Up Of Phone Number Right To Left

Tags: excel, match

I've been trying to write a number look up formula to see if some thing exists. Ideally for example looking at say xxxxxxx and then looking to match the last 8 chars from the reference value (ie xxxxx) as there are a multiple number of formats.

Using the following which I have modded from an working formula as an exact match I've tried to specify how many chars to look at how ever Excel keeps telling me I have too many arguments. I've tried a few different ways to apply this using the example "=MATCH("*"&LEFT($A8,5)&"*",'Number'!$G:$G,0)" but with no luck.

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH("*"&LEFT($A8,'Number'!$G:$G,8),"Yes",),"No"))
```

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Terran

Comment: What does the `8` (third and redundant argument of `LEFT`) represent?

Comment: Hi - based on the example I read it should be that Excel would read right to left 8 characters in for the match and not an exact match....

Comment: Your syntax is wrong.  Rewrite your formulas, from the inside out, putting one formula in each cell (and referring to the preceding cell in each subsequent formula; and you will find your error.

Comment: @TerranBrown Is this what you mean? `=IF(MATCH(RIGHT($A8, 8),$G:$G, 0), "Yes", "No")`

Comment: @GalAbra - that will never be No. You need isnumber or count to wrap the match.

Comment: Hi - =IF(MATCH(RIGHT($A8, 8),$G:$G, 0), "Yes", "No") - This gives me #NA :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use LOOKUP like below:

`=IF(ISNA(LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(RIGHT(A8,8),G:G,1))),"No","Yes")`

Or MATCH as you want:

`=IF(ISNA(MATCH("*"&RIGHT(A8,8)&"*",G:G,0)),"No","Yes")`

**Edit:** Changed formulas for differing sheet.

`=IF(ISNA(LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(RIGHT(A8,8),'Number M'!G:G,1))),"No","Yes"`

`=IF(ISNA(MATCH("*"&RIGHT(A8,8)&"*",'Number M'!G:G,0)),"No","Yes"`

Noticed one thing and which might be case with you.

If suppose A8 has `302111983588` and `'Number M'!G:G` also contains this as exact value then second formula having `MATCH` fails but `LOOKUP` works as intended.

Comment: Hi - "=IF(ISNA(LOOKUP(2^15,FIND(RIGHT(A8,8),G:G,1))),"No","Yes")" says no where I know I have an exact match and "=IF(ISNA(MATCH("*"&RIGHT(A8,8)&"*",G:G,0)),"No","Yes")" Seems to default to yes :(

Comment: @TerranBrown Both formulas have been tested with value in cell A8 being `302111983588`. Both would give the same result for the same value. Please post your sample data (small sample).

Comment: Mmmm interesting... I think I've found why I could not get my formula working... If I put the source of the data to look up on another tab ie 'Number M'!G:G it fails. If I refer to G:G on the same tab it works... I've marked the answer right but if you have any steer on why you think it fails when looking at another tab I'd be really interested...

Comment: @TerranBrown please refer to edited part and see if it helps.

Comment: Thank you very much - I will give that a go too. T